# Ошибки после переноса mysql на mysqli

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Помогите пожалуйста устранить неисправность.
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in W:\domains\bahilistich\register.php on line 68

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in W:\domains\bahilistich\register.php on line 68

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in W:\domains\bahilistich\register.php:70 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in W:\domains\bahilistich\register.php on line 70

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Регистрация</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/png">
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header" class="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="index.php">Bahilistich</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="social">
                <ul class="contact">
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook"><span>facebook</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-dribbble"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-tumblr"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-rss"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu" class="container">
            <ul>
                <li ><a href="index.php" accesskey="1" title="">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.php" accesskey="1" title="">Новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="gost.php" accesskey="2" title="">Гостевая книга (Отзывы)</a></li>
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="autoriz.php" accesskey="3" title="">Авторизация</a></li>
                <li><a href="info.php" accesskey="4" title="">Основная информация (Товары, Услуги и т.п.)</a></li>
                <li><a href="kontakty.php" accesskey="5" title="">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
//session_start();
       $host="localhost";
    $user="zettrap";
    $pass="199907zetTrap"; //установленный вами пароль
    $db_name="my_bd_zaytsev";
    $link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysqli_select_db($link,$db_name);

    //if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']))  
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
          $err=array();

          if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$_POST['login']))
          {
            $err[]="Логин может состоять только из букв английского алфавита и цифр";
          }

          if(strlen($_POST['login'])<3 or strlen($_POST['login'])>32)
          {
            $err[] = "Логин должен быть не меньше 3-х символов и не больше 32";
          }

          $query=mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])."'");

          if(mysqli_result($query, 0) > 0)
          {
            $err[] = "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует в базе данных";
          }

          if(strlen($_POST['Email'])<1)
          {
            $err[]= "Введите E-mail";
          }

          if(count($err) == 0)
          {
            $login = $_POST['login'];
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);
            $Email = $_POST['Email'];
            $pol = $_POST['pol'];
            mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users SET login='".$login."', password='".$password."', email='".$Email."', pol='".$pol."'");
            echo 'Перейти к <a href="avtorizaciya.php">авторизации</a>';
          }

          else
          {
              echo "При регистрации произошли следующие ошибки:<br>";

              foreach($err AS $error)
              {
                  echo $error;
              }
          }
        }

    
    
    
    
   /* $sql = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1) 
    {   
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
         $_SESSION['user_per'] = $row['prava'];
        if ($_SESSION['user_per']=="admin")
        {
    //header ('location: admin.php');
    echo 'Вы вошли, как админ '.$_POST['login'].' войдите в <a href="admin.php">личный кабинет</a>';
        }
        if ($_SESSION['user_per']=="user")
        {
        header ('location: user.php');
        echo 'Вы вошли, как пользователь '.$_POST['login'].' войдите в <a href="user.php">личный кабинет</a>';
        }
    }   
    else {
      die('Неверное имя пользователя или пароль');  
    }
} */
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder='Логин'><br><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder='Пароль'><br><br>
 <input type='email' name='Email' placeholder='email'>
<br> <br> Выберите пол:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select name='pol'>
              <option value='0'>Не указан</option>
              <option value='1'>Мужской</option>
              <option value='2'>Женский</option>
            </select>
 <br><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" />
</form>


    <div id="portfolio-wrapper">
        <div id="portfolio" class="container">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Бизнес по продаже бахил</h2>
                <span class="byline">производство и продажа</span> </div>
            <div class="column1">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Скидки</h3>
                    <p>На странице указаны скидки.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Скидки</a> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Доставка и оплата</h3>
                    <p>Доставка по РФ бесплатная.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Доставка и оплата</a> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Оптовикам</h3>
                    <p>Инструкции оптовикам по покупке.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Оптовикам</a> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column4">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>О магазине</h3>
                    <p>Информация о магазине.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button">О магазине</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; zettrap</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `mysqli_query()` на 68 строке должна содержать два параметра, а у вас только один

Пример
`mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City")`

Где `$link` ссылка на `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: он теперь ошибки не показывает, но и регистрацию не производит, просто без ошибок страница обновляется и всё.

Comment: Все ваши функции mysqli_query() должны содержать 2 параметра. И делайте проверку or die(mysqli_error()) в каждом запросе, так и найдёте ошибку.